# Using two input methods to control one motor shield (bluetooth and pushbuttons)

Tags: bluetooth

since an Arduino cannot run two programs simultaneously, I have been struggling a lot to get my project working - basically it is a motorized desk which is supposed to take input either from a BLE controller app or a pushbutton in order to move the linear actuators. However these inputs should work SIMULTANEOUSLY, I have failed to make both of them work together, after countless hours of prototyping, code provided below, please help me out.

```cpp
    #include <AFMotor.h>

    AF_DCMotor motor1(1, MOTOR12_64KHZ);

    AF_DCMotor motor2(2, MOTOR12_64KHZ);

    int command;

    int forwardButton = A3;

    int backwardButton = A4;

    void setup() {

      Serial.begin(9600);     

      pinMode(forwardButton, INPUT_PULLUP);

      pinMode(backwardButton,INPUT_PULLUP);

      motor1.setSpeed(255);

      motor2.setSpeed(255);

    }

    void forward(){

       motor1.run(FORWARD);

       motor2.run(FORWARD);
    }

    void backward(){

       motor1.run(BACKWARD);

       motor2.run(BACKWARD);
    }

    void stopMotor(){

       motor1.run(RELEASE);

       motor2.run(RELEASE);
    }

    void loop() {

      if (Serial.available() > 0) {

        command = Serial.read();

        stopMotor();

        switch (command) {

          case 'a':
            forward();
            break;
          case 'c':
            backward();
            break;
          case 'e':
            forward();
            break;
          case 'g':
            backward();
            break;
          case 'b':
            forward();
            break;
          case 'd':
            backward();
            break;
          case 'f':
            forward();
            break;
          case 'h':
            backward();
            break;
        }

      }
        else {

          stopMotor();

      }


    while(digitalRead(forwardButton) == LOW)

    {

      forward();  

    }

    while(digitalRead(backwardButton) == LOW)

    {

      backward();

    } 

    if(digitalRead(backwardButton)== HIGH)

    {

      stopMotor();

    }

    if(digitalRead(forwardButton) == HIGH)

    {

      stopMotor();

    }

    }
```

Comment: you did not describe the problem ... all you said is that you failed, which does not really mean anyhing specific ... you also did not say how the system should work

Comment: read through your code in loop() one line at a time and make note of what it does ... keep in mind that loop() repeats several thousand times per second